# How can I make a part of code inside the function to run after the state updates or when it is not undefined in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise, use-state

I am trying to run a code in the async block after the state updates but I am getting undefined. I tried different ways like if the state is not null then this part of the code run but it doesn't work.

My code:

```
const fileMoveHandler = async () => {
    const fileName = selectedImage.split("/").pop();
    const newPath = FileSystem.documentDirectory + fileName;
    setNewPathImage(newPath); //undefined

    try {
      await FileSystem.moveAsync({
        from: selectedImage,
        to: newPath,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error:", err);
      Alert.alert("Can't move this file.", "Try again!", [{ text: "Okay" }]);
    }
  };



const savePlaceHandler = () => {
    fileMoveHandler();
    console.log("newPathImage: ", newPathImage);

//here newPathImage is undefined

    dispatch(placesActions.addPlace(titleValue, newPathImage));
    props.navigation.goBack();
  };
```

I want to run  `dispatch` method after the state updates.

What changes should I make in my code so that it will only run if `newPathImage` is not undefined?

Should I try `promise` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useEffect` to execute dispatch when `newPath` changes

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(newPathImage){
       dispatch(placesActions.addPlace(titleValue, newPathImage));
    }
  }, [newPathImage]);
```

If you dont want it render everytime. You can put dispatch method in `fileMoveHandler`.

```
const fileMoveHandler = async () => {
    const fileName = selectedImage.split("/").pop();
    const newPath = FileSystem.documentDirectory + fileName;
    setNewPathImage(newPath); //undefined
    if(newPath){
       dispatch(placesActions.addPlace(titleValue, newPath));
       try {
         await FileSystem.moveAsync({
          from: selectedImage,
          to: newPath,
         });
       } catch (err) {
         console.log("Error:", err);
         Alert.alert("Can't move this file.", "Try again!", [{ text:"Okay" }]);
       }
    }
    
  };
```

Comment: I have tried this. `Dispatch ` method isn't dispatching if I use `if(newPathImage)` .

Comment: When do you call savePlaceHandler?

Comment: When the user clicks on the button then savePlaceHandler will execute.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Try and see

Comment: How can make it run when an event triggers like `onPress`? It will run whenever `newPathImage ` updates.

Comment: Can check my answer and try it?

Comment: Nope. Still, I same issue.

Comment: I have changed the `dispatch` method in `fileMoveHandler`.  dispatch(placesActions.addPlace(titleValue, newPath));

Comment: Yeah, I have tested your code but facing the same issue. Still undefined is passing in dispatch method.

Comment: No, i just edited the `fileMoveHandler ` method. Copy again and test it

Comment: Yes, this works. But I just want to know the different way so that I don't have to declare the `dispatch` method in `fileMoveHandler `. Is there any other way so that the dispatch method only runs when the state updates inside the function?